# Can I use Expression.Call on Generic and Static Methods?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I'm trying to use `Expression.Call` on a generic, static Method.
Unfortunately, there is no signature of the Call Method allowing to give generic type arguments AND a method info argument.

Is this possibly in any way?

What I'm concretely trying to do is to write a helper class that can sort an `IEnumerable(DataRow)` via Linq dynamically.

Unfortunately, I have to use the `DataRowExtensions` to get the Field I want to sort in the Lambda expression.

The original code comes from http://aonnull.blogspot.de/2010/08/dynamic-sql-like-linq-orderby-extension.html.

The (experimental) piece of code looks at the moment as follows:

```
//T is DataRow
Type type = typeof(T);            

IEnumerable<MethodInfo> extensions = GetExtensionMethods(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(DataRowExtensions)), typeof(DataRow));
ParameterExpression arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(DataRow), "x");

//at Position 0 there is T Field<T>(string)   
MethodInfo mi = extensions.ToList()[0];

var methArg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(String), "\"" + orderByInfo + "\"");                              
MethodCallExpression expr = Expression.Call(null, mi, arg, methArg);                          
Type delegateType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T), typeof(Object));
LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(delegateType, expr, arg);
```

When Runtime comes to the `Expression.Call` Statement an Exception is thrown saying that the Field-Method is generic.

Comment: what return `GetExtensionMethods`? why you think that `extensions.ToList()[0]` is `T Field<T>(string)  `?

Comment: IEnumerable<MethodInfo>. Had it edited now. GetExtensionMethods gives all ExtensionMethods of DataRowExtensions.DataRow with the one in question at position 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, yes. When you get *MethodInfo* for *Field* method, you really get generic method, without specify what type for return value.

```
T Field<T>(string)
```

For solving, just use `MakeGenericMethod` from this method with needed type, like

```
MethodInfo mi = extensions.ToList()[0].MakeGenericMethod(typeof(object));
```

here `mi` already specify generic parameter and present function

```
object Field(string);
```

Also you a bit complicate your code, so you can a bit simplified it and get something like this

```
//T is DataRow
Type type = typeof(T);            

IEnumerable<MethodInfo> extensions = GetExtensionMethods(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(DataRowExtensions)), type);//if T is DataRow not needed get typeof again

ParameterExpression arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(DataRow), "x");

//at Position 0 there is T Field<T>(string)   
MethodInfo mi = extensions.ToList()[0].MakeGenericMethod(typeof(object));//you can change object type to needed type

var methArg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(String), orderByInfo);//if orderByInfo already string, then not needed wrap it in quotes

LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T,string,object>>(
    Expression.Call(mi, arg, methArg), //call mi with args: arg, methArg
    arg,methArg);//pass parameters
```

*Sidenote*: you can not specify name for parameter, in this case name would be generate automatically, like: *Param_0*,*Param_1* and etc.
You anyway not use parameter name directly.

Comment: Thank you very much. You really saved my day. So I do not need Expression.Call at all here. That is a great step in the right direction.

Comment: @user1579378 try look better - `Expression.Call` used directly in `Expression.Lambda`

Comment: I was so stuck in the original code I did not see anything at all any more ;)

Comment: @user1579378, This happens :-D